# KnockoutJS: Show message when the returned array is empty

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'd like to show a message in case the returned array of tasks is empty. I used this:

```
<span data-bind="visible: tasksArr().length == 0">
   There are no tasks yet.
</span>
```

But it doesn't work properly. When I load the page, the message shows up for a second before the content is loaded into the array because `tasksArr` is declared before the request is finished fetching the content. Is there an easier way to have it show up after the load is completed without resorting to an extra observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Kdf/3/) the default value of an obervableArray is an empty array.
So there no difference between an uninitialized obervableArray and an empty obervableArray.

There are 2 work arrounds :

**Declaring more observables :**

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.tasksArr = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.initilized = ko.observable(false);
    self.canSee = ko.computed(function(){
       var a = self.tasksArr().length;
       return self.initilized() && a;
    }); 
    self.load = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                self.tasksArr.push(i);
            }
            self.initilized(true);
        }, 1000);
    }();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Kdf/4/)

**You can also delay the binding**

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.tasksArr = ko.observableArray();

    self.load = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            /*for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                self.tasksArr.push(i);
            }*/
            ko.applyBindings(x);
        }, 1000);

    }();
}

var x = new vm();
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Kdf/5/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up using just the initialized observable and then making the span show up on `tasksArr().length == 0 && initilized`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

hide the span by default (display:none;). This way, the Message will be hidden on page load and only become visible when tasksArr is indeed empty.

Comment: It won't work. The array is already empty when it's first declared, making the `span` visible on load.

Comment: I see. You could initialize the array with a dummy entry and populate it with real data upon retrieval: self.tasksArr = ko.observableArray([{}]);